# Cross platfom mobile development using C++ at backend

Tags: android, ios, mobile, blackberry

We are building a mobile app for our website which is a kind of social network. So the functionality of mobile app will be close to the Facebook app.

We are targeting Android, BlackBerry and iOS.

We tried using phonegap and other HTML, javascript solutions, but the performance for these apps was very sluggish. It was no where close to what we expect.

We are now thinking of a middle path. The front end of each platform will be native. The backend which communicates between the server and the  front end we will write in C++ . After some research I have found that, C++ code code can be consumed in different platforms in following ways

**iOS**: objective c has support to consume c++.

**Android**: [using Android NDK toolkit](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

**BlackBerry**: [BlackBerry provides a native sdk](https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_choice/ndk.html), not sure if it is what I need.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is it the right direction? Or there is some basic flaw?
2. Is there a serious time saving, by doing this? Or is it much faster to do the backend in the native?
3. Is there a noticeable difference in performance?

Comment: BlackBerry NDK is only for PlayBook and upcoming BB 10 platform

Comment: Nobody can answer #1 for sure. There will be drawbacks in every direction you choose. But I'm curious: What are the sluggish parts in HTML-based approaches? GUI? Persistence? Networking? What kind of code would you put in the backend?

Comment: @Mister we had just build a sample which was not communicating with the server at all. Still the page transitions, the speed with which the input elements (buttons/checboxes) etc responded was very slow.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs between Android and Objective-C are wildly different across the board. You will probably not be able to share communication APIs to any significant degree.

One out-there option is to standardise on Mono. Xamarin supports iOS and Android out of the box, and there's this thing called [MonoBerry](http://burningsoda.com/software/monoberry/) for Playbook and Blackberry 10. With Mono, I recommend that you standardise on SignalR for back-end communication. It's known to work on MonoTouch and Mono for Android, but you'll have to do some research for MonoBerry.

I don't know if you can get all the requisite pieces working together on all three platforms. There will almost certainly be a fair amount of bashing your head against brick walls initially. But if you do, you'll have a much more pleasant ride than with C++.